# Python : efficient bytearray incrementation

Tags: python, math, binary

How to iterate all possible values of `bytearray of length = n` in Python ?
in worst case `n <= 40bytes`

For example, iterate for `n = 4` :

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000010

.
.
.
.

11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Comment: Worst case n is probably 8; 2^64 nanoseconds = 585 years

Comment: @JasonS: It's constant time! lol

Comment: I will not need all combinations :) i just need hint how to implement that - real usage will be a little bit different.

Comment: This is better done one by one mathematically. 2^320 for all combinations is a lot of combinations. Years of time and all the memory of all computers etc... 2^320 is `2135987035920910082395021706169552114602704522356652769947041607822219725780640550022962086936576` numbers...

Comment: Yes @MartinV. How do you ever expect to reach the worst case of `2135987035920910082395021706169552114602704522356652769947041607822219725780640550022962086936576`?

Comment: Also do you need them grouped eg. first 8 bits, second 8 bits, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538456/1219006

```
n = 2
[[[i>>k&1 for k in range(j, j-8, -1)] for j in range(8*n-1, 0, -8)] 
 for i in range(2**(8*n))]
```

You'll need to run this on Python 3 for large `n` cause `xrange` doesn't support big ints.

As a generator:

```
def byte_array(n):
    for i in range(2**(8*n)):
        yield [[i>>k&1 for k in range(j, j-8, -1)] for j in range(8*n-1, 0, -8)]
```

---

```
>>> i = byte_array(4)
>>> next(i)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> next(i)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Or if you don't want them grouped it's simpler:

```
[[i>>j&1 for j in range(8*n-1, -1, -1)] for i in range(2**(8*n))]
```

Equivalent generator:

```
def byte_array(n):
    for i in range(2**(8*n)):
        yield [i>>j&1 for j in range(8*n-1, -1, -1)]
```

Comment: Great job, a can learn a lot from your code. I am working on one crypto challenge and in few tasks i need to iterate very narrow intervals of bytearrays (grouped) so i was wondering about more general case - "how to iterate all combinations...". I know it would take almost ethernity to iterate one by one :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
In [11]: from itertools import product

In [15]: for x in product('01',repeat=4): #for your n=4 change repeat to 32 
    print "".join(x)
   ....:     
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Comment: That`s great thank you. I am just reading http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product and it`s really cool.